# Python: Mapping properties of products to original precursors, to see how process changes properties

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, chemistry

There's a **list of precursor chemicals** and their computed properties, as determined by a program. The **list of metabolites** also got their properties computed. The list of metabolites isn't the same length as the list of precursors, also, they are not in order. Not all precursors are metabolized, and some form multiple metabolites.

| Identity | Properties |
| --- | --- |
| Chem 1 | properties |
| Chem 2 | properties |
| ... | ... |
| Meta 1 | properties |
| Meta 2 | properties |
| ... | ... |

I have a table which shows the which chems are metabolized into what metabolites.

| Chemical | Enzyme | Metabolite |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chem 1 | Enz 1 | Meta 1 |
| Chem 1 | Enz 2 | Meta 2 |
| Chem 3 | Enz 1 | Meta 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I want to map the properties of the metabolites side to side to properties of the properties of the precursors, to determine how properties change after metabolism, and if any chems form any particularly nasty things in the body.

I want to get a table like this:

| Chemical | Initial Properties | Properties after Metabolism | Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chem 1 | init properties | after metabolism | change |

Which I can then use to plot comparisons of the chemical and it's metabolites.

I'm using Pandas dataframes. The chemicals are written in SMILES notation.

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question. The `merge` method of dataframes may help.

Comment: Please consider sharing some sample data, by pasting it into https://pastebin.com/ and sharing the link. I think that would help with understanding the nature of the data.

Comment: provide an example of what you expect for the output please ?  combining the first 3 comments, you may wish to amend to this:  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or this [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)